# how to convert double array to collection?

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons, apache-commons-math

I have two arrays

```
   double arr[]=data.attributeToDoubleArray(4);
   double arr0[]=data.attributeToDoubleArray(0);
```

To calculate p value in common apache it has been documented as follows :

```
 public double anovaPValue(Collection<double[]> categoryData)
               throws NullArgumentException,
                      DimensionMismatchException,
                      ConvergenceException,
                      MaxCountExceededException

       Computes the ANOVA P-value for a collection of double[] arrays.
       Preconditions:

        The categoryData Collection must contain double[] arrays.
        There must be at least two double[] arrays in the categoryData collection and each of these arrays must contain at least two values.
```

How can I convert my two arrays in collection so that I can use the above function ?

Comment: `Arrays.asList(arr, arr0)` is probably the easiest way to make a `Collection<double[]>`

Comment: Collection <double[]> col = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr, arr0);`

Comment: It works. Thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

you can try this:

```
double arr[]=data.attributeToDoubleArray(4);
double arr0[]=data.attributeToDoubleArray(0);

List<double[]> newArr = Arrays.asList(arr, arr0);
```